# Mail and multiple accounts in Gmail

Tags: gmail, mail.app

I Have a gmail account configured to receive and send emails of a live mail account and I have some services that I need to send emails as live mail to be identified, but in Apple Mail I'm only able to send using the gmail account.

What I need is, using Apple Mail, send emails on behalf live mail account without having to setup the account 'cause I already receive the emails through the gmail account.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open accounts tab in preferences
2. Open any mail account you have
3. Drop down "Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)"
4. Select existing account or select "Edit SMTP Server List" to create and/or modify some.

Comment: These steps are good, but they still don't give the same functionality that gmail has: when you send from one of your alternative email addresses in gmail, not only does the server change, but the 'sent from' name and signature can be unique as well. Is there any way to set this up in mail.app? I'm with the original post-er in that my business email address already forwards to my gmail account.

Comment: I don't want to set it up as a second account in Mail because then anything that comes in will be duplicated in gmail (unless I turn off forwarding) and anything that goes out will not be saved in my gmail's outbox, which is a big concern.

Comment: This functionality is out of IMAP and SMTP standards. You can do it only with adding your accounts to Mail.app directly as Gmail does

Answer (score 3):

In the mail account settings inside Mail, you can specify several mail addresses for an account (separated by commas). When you then send mail from this account you can select the mail address to use in the message window.